# I'm coding JavaScript and html, but how to add two integers and put them in the result text

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add two integers, in the result text box. I'm trying to add them and display the formula formula like "(num1 + num2 = value)"  In the result box "5 + 5 = 10". Yet I still can not figure out how to add the integers.

Please ignore the rest the of the code, once I get the addition figure out hopefully I will be able to do the rest.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Math Tutor</title>
          <script src="mht.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<h1>Math Tutor</h1>
<lable>Enter a number</lable>
<input type="text" id="n1"><br>
<lable>Enter next number</lable>
    <input type="text" id="n2"><br>

    <input type="button" value="+" id="addNum" onclick="Addition">
  <input type="button" value="-" id="subNum" onclick="subtrack">
  <input type="button" value="/" id="divNum" onclick="divide">
  <input type="button" value="*" id="multiNum" onclick="multiply"><br>

  <input type="text" name="result" id="res" ><br><br>

  <lable>Slope Calculation</lable><br>
</body>
</html>
```

```
var $ = function(id){
return document.getElementById(id);
};

var add = function(){
  var num1 = parseInt($("n1").value);
  var num2 = parseInt($("n2").value);
 var sum = num1 + num2;
document.getElementByI("result") = (n1 "+" n2 "=" sum );
};
  window.onload = function() {
    $("Addition").onclick = add;
  };
``
```

Comment: `(n1 "+" n2 "=" sum )` this is syntactically invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldnt recommend using the `$` as it's commonly used for jQuery. Please don't use the HTML name attribute as JS id. And I changed the number input fields to `type="number"` so there won't be problems with someone writing text in it.

```js
function get(id){
return document.getElementById(id);
};

function add() {
  var num1 = parseFloat(get("n1").value);
  var num2 = parseFloat(get("n2").value);
 var sum = num1 + num2;
get("res").value = (num1 + "+" + num2 + "=" + sum );
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Math Tutor</title>
          <script src="mht.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<h1>Math Tutor</h1>
<lable>Enter a number</lable>
<input type="number" id="n1"><br>
<lable>Enter next number</lable>
    <input type="number" id="n2"><br>

    <input type="button" value="+" id="addNum" onclick="add()">
  <input type="button" value="-" id="subNum" onclick="subtract()">
  <input type="button" value="/" id="divNum" onclick="divide()">
  <input type="button" value="*" id="multiNum" onclick="multiply()"><br>

  <input type="text" name="result" id="res" ><br><br>

  <lable>Slope Calculation</lable><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: WOW!!!! thank you, dev village for the suggestion... I learn way faster when I know it the code works and break it down why it works. I REALLY understand your code. If it's not too much to ask... What are some good tips when learning JavaScript?

Comment: just keep going, watch some tutorials and do your own projects. whenever u get stuck stack is always a great help, at least it was to me. also the w3 documentation is a good resource!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for individual functions for each operation - simply assign a single event handler to all of the buttons and use other logic ( in this case the value of the button ) to determine what operations to perform. Using `parseFloat` rather than `parseInt` to process the user input allows for ( unsurprisingly ) floats rather than integers.
Whilst it is not a problem using an `input` element to display the result it does seem unusual - especially given that there is an HTML element specifically for situations like this - namely the `output` element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Math Tutor</title>
        <style>
            html, html *{ box-sizing:border-box; }

            body{ margin:0; padding:0; display:flex; flex-direction:column; align-items:center; align-content:center; justify-content:center; width:100%;height:100vh;font-family:calibri,verdana,arial; }
            form{ display:flex; justify-content:center; border:1px solid black; width:80%; height:50%; margin:auto; }

            h1{ writing-mode: vertical-rl; transform: rotate(180deg); font-size: 1.5rem; letter-spacing: 0.15rem; margin:auto; background:black; color:white; height:100%; padding:0.5rem; text-align:center; }
            label{ display:flex; flex:1; align-items:center; flex-direction:row; width:100%; padding:0.5rem; margin:auto; }
            label:before{content:attr(data-label);text-transform:capitalize}

            input{ padding:0.5rem;margin:auto }

            div{ display:flex; flex-direction:row; flex:1; padding:1rem; margin:auto; }
            div > input{ flex:1;margin:0 0.25rem }

            output{ width:60%; height:3rem; margin:auto; text-align:center; font-size:2rem; }
        </style>
        <script>

            /* utility to emulate PHP's `sprintf` function for formatting a string */
            String.prototype.sprintf = function() {
                return [ ...arguments ].reduce( ( p,c ) => p.replace(/%s/,c), this );
            };

            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{

                /* get references to the form elements */
                let form=document.forms.mathtutor;
                let number_1=form.querySelector('input[type="number"][name="number-1"]');
                let number_2=form.querySelector('input[type="number"][name="number-2"]');
                let output=document.querySelector('output');

                /* obtain reference to the function buttons and assign event handler */
                Array.prototype.slice.call( form.querySelectorAll('div > [type="button"]') ).forEach( bttn=>{
                    bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
                        let product;

                        /* ensure that the values from the input elements are numbers */
                        let i1=parseFloat( number_1.value );
                        let i2=parseFloat( number_2.value );

                        /* perform whatever calculation is required according to button pressed */
                        switch( this.value ){
                            case '+':   product=i1 + i2; break;
                            case '-':   product=i1 - i2; break;
                            case '/':   product=i1 / i2; break;
                            case 'x':   product=i1 * i2; break;
                        }

                        /* format the output and display the result */
                        output.innerText='%s %s %s = %s'.sprintf( i1, this.value, i2, product );
                    });
                })
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name='mathtutor' method='post'>
            <h1>Mathematics tutor</h1>
            <label for='number-1' data-label='number 1'><input type='number' name='number-1' required /></label>
            <label for='number-2' data-label='number 2'><input type='number' name='number-2' required /></label>
            <div>
                <input type='button' value='+' />
                <input type='button' value='-' />
                <input type='button' value='/' />
                <input type='button' value='x' />
            </div>
        </form>
        <output></output>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Woah your code is a way higher level than mine. I will look over and break it down. Thank you.